# convert integer at y axis into date

Tags: python, date-conversion

I have data in which the y-axis represents the number of segments of 12 hours, for example, the first value is 1  which represents 2019-08-07, 12:00, and the second's values represent 2019-08-08,00:00.
Is there any way to convert this to Python?
**I tried in Matlab which works well, not sure about python**.

```
bd=[2019 08 07]
day=1:381          
sg=12               %represent the hours in each segments 
YTickStr = char(datetime(bd, 'InputFormat', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'Format', 'dd/MM/yy') + hours(day*sg));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer, I just solved it.

```
yaxis=[] #empty 
startdate = "08/07/2019"
for i in day:
    end_date = pd.to_datetime(startdate) + pd.DateOffset(hours=12*i)
    yaxis.append(end_date)
```